# How to get row from db with condition - another exists in another table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I have two tables `notifications` and `archived_notifications`.

*Notifications*

`id | title | caption | user_id`

*Archived notifications*

`notification_id | user_id`

How SQL request should looks if I want to get rows from `notifications` table for which there is no row in the `archived_notifications` table like `notification_id = notification.id | user_id = notification.user_id`.

Now I have some like this

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM notifications AS n WHERE "
                   "({}=%s AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM archvies WHERE {}=n.id AND {}=%s) = 0) "
                   "OR "
                   "({}=%s AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM archvies WHERE {}=n.id AND {}=%s) = 0) "
                   "ORDER by id DESC LIMIT %s OFFSET %s"
                   .format(Keys.USER_ID, Keys.NOTIFICATION_ID, Keys.USER_ID, Keys.DIRECTION, Keys.NOTIFICATION_ID,
                           Keys.USER_ID),
                   [str(user_id), str(user_id), NotificationsClasses.GLOBAL, str(user_id), int(limit), int(offset)])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you can use either of the [NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/16/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-postgresql/) clauses. Specifically, you appear to have a number of other unclear conditions such as the *direction* handling and string formatting of column names from unknown *Keys* variables.

Below shows the `NOT EXISTS` option with attempted translation of your current code. Adjust to actual needs:

```
sql = '''SELECT * FROM notifications AS n 
         WHERE n.user_id = %s
           AND NOT EXISTS
              (SELECT 1 FROM archives a
               WHERE a.user_id = %s
                 AND n.id = a.notification_id)
         ORDER by n.id DESC 
         LIMIT %s 
         OFFSET %s
      '''

cursor.execute(sql, [str(user_id), NotificationsClasses.GLOBAL, int(limit), int(offset)])
```

Comment: Great! Glad to help. Happy coding.